# Map Caps Lock to Escape for server not running X

Tags: linux, console, keyboard-layout

I am using xmodmap to remap the capslock key to escape for my Linux system running X.

I am now working directly on a headless Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server that does **not** run X. Is there any easy way to get the same behavior in the system terminal as well, when directly logged in to the machine and typing on a USB keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried `loadkeys`?  (It's in the `kbd` package in Debian)